# Merging onclick/toggle with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

So I'm building a notification system and when I click the onclick button it opens the div with the notifications. At the same time I'd like to update the database as seen and the red image that shows will then dissapear.

How would I code the ajax to get the onclick toggle?

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#"  onclick="toggle('alert_dropdown');">
    <div class="alert_header_item" id="alerts"></div>
</a>
<div style="display:none;" id="alert_dropdown" class="alert_dropdown">
<div style="padding: 5px; width: 290px; max-height: 50%; overflow: hidden;">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

       //onclick code here

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'readnotifications.php',
            data: {id: user_id},
        }).success(function(data) {
            // do what you need to do as notifications were read.
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: `toggle('alert_dropdown');yourajaxfuntion();`

Comment: @Up this is not really good because this way you toggle your dropdown no matter if your ajax-request did suceed or fail. Due to timeout, code-error/bug or whatever an ajax operation can fail at any time.